# How to make callback function in Coffeescript

Tags: callback, coffeescript

I can't find out how to make a function that calls another function at the end.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
book.save (err) ->
  MyFunc param1, param2, (callbackParam) ->
    # some code using callbackParam

MyFunc = (param1, param2) ->
  # some other code that defines callbackParam
  ?.call(callbackParam)
```

What has to be called and how does it receive the data?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to call `MyFunc` as:

```
MyFunc param1, param2, some_function
```

Then it should look like this:

```
MyFunc = (param1, param2, callback) ->
    # some code that defines callbackParam
    callback callbackParam
```

And if you want to make the `callback` optional:

```
MyFunc = (param1, param2, callback) ->
    # some code that defines callbackParam
    callback? callbackParam
```

And if you want to supply a specific `@` (AKA `this`), then you'd use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) just like in JavaScript:

```
MyFunc = (param1, param2, callback) ->
    # some code that defines callbackParam
    callback?.call your_this_object, callbackParam
```

The `(callbackParam) -> ...` stuff is just a function literal that acts like any other parameter, there's no special block handling like in Ruby (your tags suggest that Ruby blocks are the source of your confusion).